# No module named 'PIL' only in pycharm (works well at IDLE)

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python3 by using cs1robots library.
So I typed "from cs1robots import*"
This code works at python IDLE but not works at Pycharm saying "No module named 'PIL' "
I hope to find answer for it!

Comment: Have you installed `PIL` for the interpreter being used by PyCharm?

Comment: I installed the pillow by typing "py –m pip
install Pillow" at cmd. Should I have to do something for Pycharm?

Comment: Pycharm supports multiple virtual environments, so it's possible that your project is not using the system python environment. Run that same command in the pycharm console.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `PIL` in Pycharm separately. You can do the following

1) Write your code in Pycharm
2) File > Setting > "Your Opened Project" > Click on the add sign (+)
3) Then search for the relevant package in the search bar

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing new environment to existing environment in Pycharm setting.